# Robots.TXT and Meta Tag Robots

Tags: meta-tags, robots.txt

I want to make sure I understand this:

This: `<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots" />` in the `<head>` of a webpage

is the same as:

`Disallow: /example-page.html` in the `Robots.txt`

Right?

Comment: @casperOne - I am curious as to how this is off topic? It is a web development question about Robots.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in the <head> of a webpage is the same as:` Yes, if you are talking about the `<head>` of the `example-page.html`. The only difference is that when you have restriction for bots in the meta tag, the page will still be requested by the spider. This might be essential if that page is generated by any server-side script and you count the number of times it was displayed or gather any other information related to the visits to this page (from access logs, for example).

The bot (the valid bot from normal search engines) will access the page, read the meta tag, and subsequently not index it, while with the record in `robots.txt` no request of the page will be performed by the generic spider or the one mentioned in `User-agent` section of `robots.txt`.